# Tem como usar uma variável que esta dentro do for?

Tags: php, variáveis, foreach, heredoc

Por exemplo. Estou trabalhando com Heredoc e sempre que preciso fazer um *for*, tenho que fechar o Heredoc fazer o *for* depois abrir novamente a Tag mencionada.

Tem alguma forma de consultar uma variável dentro do for que me retornará todos os resultados? Por ex.:

```
$telefones = 3;
for($i = 0; $i < $telefones; $i++) {
     $numero_tel = $buscar_telefones[$i]['numero'];
     $todosNumeros = "telefone: $numero_tel";
}
echo <<< EOT
     $todosNumeros
EOT;
```

PRINT : telefone: 9999-9999 telefone: 9999-7777 telefone: 9999-8888

Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Só declarar a variável antes, fora do [**`for()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php).

Tem mais algumas alterações que precisam ser feitas, conforme abaixo:

```
$todosNumeros = "";
$telefones = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $telefones; $i++) {
     $numero_tel = $buscar_telefones[$i]['numero'];
     $todosNumeros .= "telefone: " . $numero_tel . " ";
}
echo <<< EOT
     $todosNumeros
EOT;
```

Comment: Esta me retornando erro `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR`

Comment: Desculpe, eu usei uma sintaxe do PHP4. Veja agora.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma porém ele retornou um número só. Não retornou os tres. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Fiz várias correções. Veja se agora lhe atende.

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez não é obrigatório criar a variável antes, fora do for. Uma variável criada dentro do for pode ser perfeitamente acessada de fora dele.

Comment: É que eu fui mais pelo título da pergunta, mas você tem razão.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode perfeitamente utilizar, fora do for, qualquer variável criada dentro do contexto do [**`for()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php), e não é obrigatório criá-lo ele antes;

```
$telefones = 3;
for($i = 0; $i < $telefones; $i++) {
     $numero_tel = $buscar_telefones[$i]['numero'];
     $todosNumeros .= "telefone: $numero_tel ";
}

echo $todosNumeros;
```

Comment: Você esta correto. Porém para oque eu preciso, tenho que limpar a variável, senão ela me retornará números que já existiam nas anteriores. @LeoFelipe Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sim, se a variável já existir de outro contexto e tiver valores, ela deverá ser zerada para não impactar nas regras do seu loop.